# Delete CosmosDB Container Items

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create an Azure Function (implemented in Python) to delete an item in a CosmosDB container. Using Azure Cosmos DB Input & Output bindings, I was able to add, query and update items but I was not able to find a method that could delete one. Is it possible to delete an item using the binding methods?

The following code is what I am currently using to do a simple update.

_*init*_.py file

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, doc: func.Out[func.Document]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    departure_time = ""
    arrival_time = ""

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        bc_id_no = req_body.get('bc_id_no')
        trip_id = req_body.get('trip_id')
        departure_time = req_body.get('departure_time')
        arrival_time = req_body.get('arrival_time')

    if bc_id_no and trip_id:
        newdocs = func.DocumentList() 

        input_dict = {
            "bc_id_no": bc_id_no,
            "id": trip_id,
            "departure_time": departure_time,
            "arrival_time": arrival_time
        }

        newdocs.append(func.Document.from_dict(input_dict))
        doc.set(newdocs)
        
        return func.HttpResponse(f"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "bc_id_no or trip_id not available",
             status_code=200
        )
```

function.json

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "update_rec"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "doc",
      "databaseName": "mockDB",
      "collectionName": "mockCollection",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AzureCosmosDBConnectionString"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

Understand that it may be possible to use the sqlQuery configuration properties for the input binding to specify a delete statement (not too sure if this is a good practice even..) but just wondering if another method for deletion is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bindings only support querying, reading (Input binding), or adding (Output binding), there is no Delete support.

There is no configuration you can pass that would make the binding execute a Delete, it's just not there in the code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/tree/cosmos/v3.x/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB

The only alternative I can think of is if you used the Python SDK directly inside the Function to perform the delete: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-python

Just make sure that the instance is created and maintained outside of the execution scope: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#static-clients